# Serving django compressed files in production

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

when deploying a Django solution in production, I ran into a problem with compressed and compiled static files. I have Django running under a Nginx reverse proxy that also takes care of serving static files.

Some of the files (notably js and css files) are not found, and I notice that this happens because of the compression enabled by the following settings in settings.py

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (

    ('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'), 
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.jsmin.JSMinFilter'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # [..]
    'compressor',
    # [..]
)
```

So, what is the most correct way to freeze the precompilations and compressions in order to deploy them in production? Thanks

Comment: How do you access those compressed files? Just remember that compressed files are usually cached under `CACHE` directory within your `STATIC_ROOT` with name different from original name.

Answer (score 0):

additional to the above comment, maybe its worth to look at this

```
https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a way to compress files on your dev machine, before deploying:

```
./manage.py compress --force
```

You should also set COMPRESS_OFFLINE in settings:

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
if 'compress' in sys.argv:
    # compressor related settings when called as management command
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
    COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
```